# geom_line produces broken line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a continuous variable against year, but my line plot is broken, how do I fix it? I've tried dropping NAs but it does not help

```
data %>% mutate(quarternum=str_sub(quarter,-1,-1), year=str_sub(quarter,1,4)) %>% filter(quarternum==1) %>% drop_na() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_line(linetype = "solid") +
  labs(x="Quarter",
       y="Singapore Property Index") +
  theme(axis.text.x= element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1.3, vjust = 1.2, size=7.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, group = 1))`.

Comment: can you provide an example of your data and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple measurements per year it appears. Perhaps 4 since it seems you are working with quarterly data? So what do you want to show on the y axis then? Having a line through all 4 points for eavery year isn't going to look very meaningful.

Perhaps the mean per year?

Here's a suggestion:

```r
set.seed( 100 )
d <- data.frame(
    x = rep( 1975:2018, each=4 )
)
d$y  <- 10 + (d$x-1975)*rnorm( length(d$x), mean=5, sd=.2 )
ggplot( d, aes(x=x,y=y) ) +
    geom_point( size=1, col="darkgrey" ) +
    stat_summary( aes(group=1), fun="mean", geom="line" )
```